# Spark logic similar to zipWithUniqueId but on Dataframe instead of RDD

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to create a function similar to `zipWithUniqueId` that calculates a unique value based on the partition ID, and row index within the partition.  I'd like to do this directly on a DataFrame rather than going from DF to RDD and back to DF.

I tried to copy [`monotonically_increasing_id`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/MonotonicallyIncreasingID.scala) and replace the logic, but the issue is the logic needs to know how many total partitions there are, not just the ID of the current partition.

Is this a reasonable alternative (Scala syntax but PySpark should be equivalent):

```
val partitionCount = df.rdd.getNumPartitions()

val window = Window.partitionBy($"__partition")
df.withColumn("__partition", spark_partition_id())
  .withColumn("__row_in_partition", row_number().over(window))
  .withColumn("id", ($"__row_in_partition" - 1) * lit(partitionCount) + $"__partition" + lit(1))
```

Is this a safe and valid approach?  The main risk I see is if the result of `df.rdd.getNumPartitions` doesn't reflect the number of actual partitions at the time of the other expressions evaluating.